# mat-autocomplete show the list only on search text

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I am building an app and I have the mat-autocomplete. I wanted to show the searched list only on  entering certain text in the input text field. I tried certain ways but no luck

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{option.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create functions in component.ts.then it works fine. follow the below steps respectively.

HTML Component

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name">
            {{option.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Insert the following code inside your constructor.

```
this.filteredOptions = this.myControl?.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
);
```

Create a method called _filter to get all autocomplete values.

```
_filter(value: any): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
}
```

**Important - make sure that this.options mean all the assignee**

Comment: With this, even by clicking the search item, the list shows up even before entering the text. I need to show list only on entering certain text on the search text.

Comment: It can't happen because the condition ` return this. options. filter (option => option. name. toLowerCase(). IndexOf (filterValue) === 0);` returns  an array with name that you inserted in input field

Comment: @indra257 Remove startWith('') . Intially list will be empty. On input list start filtering values.